# Java KeyListener dissappears when adding new object

Tags: java, swing, jframe, keylistener, pong

Brand new to this forum. Tried to learn Java by tutorials for a while, which have worked fine until now when I'm playing around with Swing making a Pong game..

My problem is that when I try to change level in my game my player's keylistener stops working.

I have tried to remove all unnecessary code, hopefully I haven't missed any that causes confusion.
This is what happens in my Main-class, where Data is basically a JPanel working as my background and Player is Another JPanel, I'll get to the Player-class after main.

```
public class Main {
Data data = new Data(Color.RED);
Player player = new Player(700, 500, 20, 100);
public Main() throws InterruptedException{
    run(data, player);
            ballRecursive();
                    }

public void run(Data data) throws InterruptedException {
    frame.add(player, BorderLayout.WEST);
    frame.add(data, BorderLayout.CENTER);
}

public void ballRecursive() throws InterruptedException {
    if(playerScore.returnScore()==1){
        Data data = new Data(Color.GREEN);
        run(data);
}
```

This is my Player, tried to remove anything unnecessary here aswell:

```
public class Player extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener{
Timer timer = new Timer(5, this);

double yPos = 0, movementY = 0;
int squareSize = 60;

int yBound;

public Player(int w, int h, int width, int height) {
    timer.start();

    addKeyListener(this);
    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
    yBound = (windowHeight - squareSize);

}
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    yPos += movementY;

    if (yPos < 0) {
        yPos = 0;
    } else if (yPos + squareSize > yBound) {
        yPos = yBound - squareSize;
    }

    repaint();
}

public void moveUp() 
{

    if (yPos == 0) 
    {
        movementY = 0;
    }
    movementY = -1;
}

public void moveDown() 
{
    if (yPos == yBound) 
    {
        movementY = 0;           
    }

    movementY = 1;
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) 
{
    int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();

    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
        moveUp();
    }

    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
        moveDown();
    }

}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
{
    int keyCode = e.getKeyCode();

    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_UP) 
    {
        movementY = 0;
    }

    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) 
    {
        movementY = 0;
    }
```

Comment: *"Another problem.."* SO is a Q&A site, not a help desk. Each thread should have ***one*** clear, specific question with a [mcve] particular to that question. Please decide which problem you dealt with in this thread, form a question around that problem, and [edit] the post to remove the other matter & start a new thread on that. The basic problem appears to be (from a cursory look) that the `Player` should not be a `JComponent` but instead simply know how to draw itself to a `Graphics` object when asked to do so. The custom rendered panel should maintain a **list** of things to draw.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I see. The problem is the KeyListener, so I removed the other part. Regarding your answer; should that really make my KeyListener start responding again?

Comment: `My problem is that when I try to change level in my game my player's keylistener stops working.` How? By clicking on another component? Then the "player" loses focus, so KeyEvents will no longer be passed to the player. Don't use a KeyListener. Instead use [Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) so you don't have a focus issue.

Comment: @camickr That's the thing; it just loses the focus, only difference is that the frame gets a new Data. Yea I'm looking on Keybinders right now, so far it feels a bit tricky for a noob like myself.

Comment: Update: Tried Keybinder but it still won't work, the second I go to the next level in my game I cannot move my Player.